# file integrity checksum failed for "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4"

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, docker-image, docker-aws

I am pushing my docker image to AWS ECS. And, I am getting following error:
file integrity checksum failed for "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4"

Here is the full output:

```
The push refers to repository [myaddress.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myrepositoryname]
3d4763f6944c: Layer already exists 
5d22ab3cff2d: Layer already exists 
080db391ad2c: Layer already exists 
7030a45b5de7: Layer already exists 
5d98bab77a5b: Layer already exists 
f08694a3abdb: Layer already exists 
c4cfb93dc085: Layer already exists 
1a38a1227cbb: Layer already exists 
caa05d68a0ed: Layer already exists 
891119e77426: Layer already exists 
1f912505da6e: Layer already exists 
f1e810a48819: Layer already exists 
a47630fbce4f: Layer already exists 
09fc3edb847c: Layer already exists 
6b60013e5875: Pushing [==================================================>]  323.9MB/323.9MB
d6335a641f5e: Layer already exists 
5c33df241050: Layer already exists 
ffc4c11463ee: Layer already exists 
file integrity checksum failed for "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3.4.4"
```

Is there any solution for the above issue? I tried to build an image again and also increased allocated memory in docker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

docker system prune -a

And then create a new image and push.

Comment: Caution: The prune command above will remove all unused images! Even those not related to this push.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a similar error, though in my case it was related to the NPM cache.

```
file integrity checksum failed for "root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/d1/32/a7a1c3a9679bc2b3533e44dd7850d81c4c257024e9f32854b681383a5ed1c191412124a0d316bea11daa019c2bee1bf18770034bd53db117aedc09339b0b
```

All I had to do was full build with the `--no-cache` option, e.g.:

```
docker build --no-cache .
```

Push to AWS was successful after the full build.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i was trying to save my docker image with

```
docker save mipscrosscompilation -o mipsCrossCompilation.tar
```

i found that the problem is in one of the commits. So i merged the layers of my image following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56118557/9546063
i created a new version of the image by merging the layers the i could save it successfully.

Greetings,